# How to render more than 1 object in list at once in Processing?

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I'm trying to render 2 buttons in Processing but I don't know how to update them all....

```
Button[] cudels = new Button[100];
void setup()
{
 size(1200, 800);
  odvody();
}

void odvody()
{
cudels[1] = new Button(width/2, height/2, 200, 50, "I need Water",20,  255, 
0, 255);  

cudels[2] = new Button(width/2, 20, 200, 50, "I need some LAAAVAA" ,20,  255, 
255, 0);

cudels[].update();
cudels[].render();
}
```

Comment: Loop over the array. You can't call the `update` and `render` methods on the arrays themselves. Java arrays don't have those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cudels.length; i++) {
  if (cudels[i] != null) {
    cudels[i].update();
    cudels[i].render();
  }
}
```